# Branching Other Activities off TabActivity Activity

Tags: java, android, listview, tabactivity

So I have a TabActivity that branches into three sub-activities (tabs). One of these activities is a ListView, which I want to branch into further ListView activities. However, I want each of these branched ListViews to also have the same tabs at the top. To do this, do I need to create a separate TabActivity and a separate Activity for each of these branched ListViews? Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch from the old deprecated APIs using like `TabActivity` or `ActivityGroup` into `Fragment`s.

> This class was deprecated in API level 13.
>
> New applications should use Fragments instead of this class; to continue to run on older devices, you can use the v4 support library which provides a version of the Fragment API that is compatible down to DONUT.

From [TabActivity documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html).

Answer (score 1):

Cannot you trick a user into having TabActivities, but instead simply have one `ListView` instance with  3 buttons on the top of an activity (Tabs) and every time user clicks one of the "fake" tabs, just refresh the existing `ListView` with views that are appropriate for one of those "fake" tabs. In my opinion this solution would be more efficient resource-wise and render time -wise (which anyway are dual concepts)

This is what I have in mind
[image]

You may use `Fragments` as proposed by [MaciejGórski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2183804/maciejgorski) for `TabActivityOne`, `TabActivityTwo` and `TabActivityThree`, while the ListView inflation technique could still be used